# Isomorphism of bundles , Madsen's Calculus to Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\xi=(E,M,p)$ be a smooth bundle over $M$. Denote $\Omega^0(\xi)$ the smooth sections.

We also define $\Omega^i(M):= \Omega^0(\wedge^i T^*M)$, differential $i$ forms, and $\Omega^0(M)$ is then smooth functions on $M$ to $\Bbb R$.

---

Then in Madsen's book Calculus to Cohomology, page 171, it states

> $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega^0(M)}(\Omega^0(\xi), \Omega^2(M) \otimes_{\Omega^0(M)} \Omega^0(\xi)) \cong  \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega^0(M)}(\Omega^0(\xi), \Omega^0(\xi)) \otimes _{\Omega^0(M)} \Omega^2(M)$$

---

I don't understand why this is true. In fact, if we relabel everything, 
$$\operatorname{Hom}_R(A,B \otimes_RS) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(A,B) \otimes_R S$$ 
is what we have to show. But there is only a map clear from one direction, from RHS to LHS, 
$$ (f \otimes s ) (a):= f(a) \otimes s $$

---

How does one prove the isomorphism?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take $A=B=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R=S=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You are right that the generalization does not hold. But there is something different about the case stated. Fiber wise, we have an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: I believe that the map $\nu$ defined by $\nu(f\otimes c)(a)=f(a)\otimes c$ is an isomorphism $\nu:Hom_R(A,B)\otimes_RC\cong Hom_R(A,B\otimes_RC)$ when either $A$ or $C$ is a finitely generated projective $R$-module. (I don't see the problem with Hempelicious's example above). Then the statement should hold since the sections of $E$ form a locally-free $C^\infty(M)$ module of dimension equal to the rank of $E$. I don't have a good reference to hand, so hopefully you'll be able to track one down.

Comment: Actually, this was linked to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072208/hom-kv-v-otimes-k-w-cong-hom-kv-v-otimes-k-w?noredirect=1&lq=1, and seems to cover most of what you want.

Comment: @Tyrone: in my example, the lhs is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the rhs is $0$. You probably need $R$ to be a field to get the isomorphism in general.

Comment: @Hempelicious You have $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Q}$ and $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\cong Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q})$. Therefore $Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z})\cong Hom_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q})\cong Hom(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}$, so it holds. Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: @Tyrone: No, the mistake is mine! I meant $A=S=\mathbb{Q}$ and $R=B=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the book doesn't just state this fact; it cites Theorem 16.13 from earlier in the book as justification.  That theorem says that the operation of tensoring and Homming sections of vector bundles over the ring $\Omega^0(M)$ corresponds to the tensor and Hom operations on the vector bundles themselves.  In particular, there are natural isomorphisms $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega^0(M)}(\Omega^0(\xi), \Omega^2(M) \otimes_{\Omega^0(M)} \Omega^0(\xi))\cong \Omega^0(\operatorname{Hom}(\xi,\wedge^2T^*M\otimes \xi))$$ and $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega^0(M)}(\Omega^0(\xi), \Omega^0(\xi)) \otimes _{\Omega^0(M)} \Omega^2(M)\cong \Omega^0(\operatorname{Hom}(\xi,\xi)\otimes\wedge^2T^*M).$$
The desired isomorphism then follows from the isomorphism of vector bundles $\operatorname{Hom}(\xi,\wedge^2T^*M\otimes \xi)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(\xi,\xi)\otimes\wedge^2T^*M$, which on fibers is just the natural isomorphism of vector spaces $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W\otimes V)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(V,V)\otimes W$.