# $Hom_k(V,V \otimes_k W) \cong Hom_k(V,V)\otimes_k W$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am thinking the following statement is true:

> Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces. Then we have 
>   $$ Hom_k(V,V \otimes_kW)\cong Hom_k(V,V) \otimes_kW$$

---

My attempt: EDIT ( I noticed I have typed up some nonsense)

There is a map from RHS to LHS, sending $f \otimes_k w$ to element 
$$ (f \otimes_k w) (v) = f(v) \otimes _k w  $$

---

Motivation: this is an attempt to solve the [more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072181/isomorphism-of-bundles-madsens)

Comment: It's not enough to show that the basis has a nontrivial image to conclude that it's an isomorphism

Comment: Moreover $f(v) (v\otimes w)$ makes no sense : $f(v) \in V$ and $v\otimes w\in V\otimes W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things : first of all, notice that they have the same dimension as $k$-vector spaces, so they are automatically isomorphic.

Now the problem is that the isomorphism you get depends a lot on $V,W$, it's not "natural" or "canonical".

Then, note that what you wrote doesn't make sense : $f(v)(v\otimes w)$ is not even well-typed : both $f(v)$ and $v\otimes w$ are vectors.

Another thing is that when you have finite dimensional vector spaces, $\hom_k(E,F)\simeq E^*\otimes F$, the isomorphism being given from the RHS to the LHS by $l\otimes v \mapsto (x\mapsto l(x)v)$.

So in your situation, $\hom_k(V,V\otimes W)\simeq V^*\otimes (V\otimes W) \simeq (V^*\otimes V)\otimes W\simeq \hom_k(V,V)\otimes W$, which shows that for finite dimensional spaces there is actually a natural isomorphism.

Now what does my isomorphism do ? Let's see from the RHS to the LHS what it does : let $f\in \hom_k(V,V)$, $w\in W$. If the matrix of $f$ in $(e_i)$ is $(a_{ij})$ then our isomorphism sends $f\otimes_k w$ to $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}(e_i^*\otimes e_j \otimes w)$. This is sent to $g\in \hom_k(V,V\otimes W)$

To $v=\displaystyle\sum_i v_i a_i$, this sends $\displaystyle\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}e_i^*(v)(e_j \otimes w) = \displaystyle\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}v_i (e_j\otimes w) = f(v)\otimes w$.

Ok so now without the isomorphism I introduced we can still define $\hom_k(V,V)\otimes W\to \hom_k(V,V\otimes W), f\otimes w\mapsto (v\mapsto  f(v)\otimes w)$.

To prove it is injective for instance, you can use a basis but not the way you did : it's not enough to show that your morphism is nontrivial on elements of a basis to show that it is injective. Indeed if $(e_i)$ is any basis, $\displaystyle\sum_i e_i^*$ is nonzero on all basis elements, but it's definitely not injective in dimensions $\geq 2$.

But what you can do is, calling the morphism $g$, find a suitable basis $a_i$ and see what $g(\displaystyle\sum_i \lambda_i a_i) = 0$ tells you. Here, if $(e_i), (f_j)$ are bases of $V,W$ respectively, you have a canonical basis for $\hom_k (V,V)\otimes W$ that can help you prove the injectivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made severe mistake in defining the first map, I am sorry for that :( But my point wasn't in showing that the image of basis is nontrivial - but they in fact map to linearly independent elements. It seems unclear to me what you are doing at the end, but it seems it boils down to showing $Hom_k(E,F) \cong E^* \otimes F$? I guess this is the argument: $e_i^* \otimes f_j $ maps to linearly independent elements, for a choice of basis. By dimensions, we have an isomorphism.

Comment: At the end I was just showing how you could prove the map I defined is an isomorphism without using $\hom(E,F)\simeq E^*\otimes F$. And yes, this is essentially the proof

Comment: I wonder what your thoughts are on the related post? I think it follows from this special case.

Comment: The $\Omega^i(M)$ don't seem to be finite dimensional, I don't see how it would follow (though I don't know much differential geometry). But you do have a map in one direction, perhaps you can try to see why it is an iso in your situation